# API returning unsupported media type in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following API when I do a request to it, it returns unsupported media type I have no idea what is causing this problem.

```
[HttpPost("select/manager/{projectId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> SetProjectManager([FromBody] string name, string projectId)
{
    var (isValid, username, password) = spManager.GetCredentials(HttpContext.Request.Headers["x-token"]);

    if (!isValid || string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        return BadRequest("Bad Key!");
    }

    var result = await spManager.SetProjectManager(username, password, name, projectId);

    if (result.Success == true)
    {
        return Ok(new SubmissionResponse { Success = true, ErrorCode = null });
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound(new SubmissionResponse { Success = false, ErrorCode = "Not Found!" });
    }
}
```

I am sending a token in the header but it's not shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: "The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format." [415 Unsupported Media Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415)

Comment: You need to set the content type header of the request to the JSON media type.

Comment: try to use {"name":"cristof"} and select Json instead of text

Answer (score 2):

replace "cristof" with {"name": "cristof"} and change the body type to Json.

Comment: I did what you suggest but it didn't work so I created a class model for the manager that contains one property which is the name then I read this property from the body instead of the string name and it worked, but I don't know if this is the best solution...thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

> when I do a request to it, it returns unsupported media type

The [HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415) error indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format. And please note that it doesn't provide a built-in input formatter for plain text in ASP.NET Core Web APIs.

The framework provides built-in input and output formatters for JSON and XML. To make the request with your data work well, as @Nkosi suggested, you can try to change the `Content-Type` to `application/json`.

[image]

Besides, if you really want your APIs work well with plain text input, you can try to implement a custom plain text input formatter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

It's a nuisance this doesn't "just work" out of the box for such a simple request. You can do below as a workaround, with no [FromBody] parameter:

```
var rawBody = "";
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, encoding: Encoding.UTF8, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false)) {
   rawBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```